# Help creating a Network Namespace to run a VPN

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, openvpn

My intention is to setup a Network Namespace which will have a VPN running in it.  I plan on having certain applications configured to start in that Namespace to be behind the VPN.  Anything not configured to run in the Namespace should go out the regular internet connection.  This is as far as I've gotten (not my work so I'm struggling to understand what is wrong and what needs to occur next).

This is being run on Ubuntu 18.04.1

- Create `etc/iproute2/rt_tables.d` and add the following to it:

  `sudo echo "3 pia-vpn" > /etc/iproute2/rt_tables.d/pia.conf`
- Create `/etc/init.d/pia-namespace` and add the following to it:

`# !/bin/bash`

```
# /etc/init.d/pia-namespace

# Create pia namespace and interface pairs
ip netns add pia
ip link add to-pia type veth peer name pia-in
ip link add from-pia type veth peer name pia-out

# Put one of each pair inside the namespace
ip link set pia-in netns pia
ip link set pia-out netns pia

# IP addresses and bring up interfaces outside
ip addr add dev to-pia 192.168.234.2/30
ip link set dev to-pia up
ip addr add dev from-pia 192.168.234.6/30
ip link set dev from-pia up

# IP addresses and bring up interfaces inside
ip netns exec pia ip addr add 192.168.234.1/30 dev pia-in
ip netns exec pia ip addr add 192.168.234.5/30 dev pia-out
ip netns exec pia ip link set dev lo up
ip netns exec pia ip link set dev pia-in up
ip netns exec pia ip link set dev pia-out up

# Pia default route
ip netns exec pia ip route add default via 192.168.234.6 dev pia-out

# Pia return route
ip netns exec pia ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.234.2 dev pia-in

# iptables
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i to-pia -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i to-pia -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -o to-pia -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i from-pia -o enp0s3 -j DROP   # Don't leak traffic to the internet
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i from-pia -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o from-pia -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Send outgoing traffic from the namespace to the VPN table
ip rule add from 192.168.234.5 lookup pia-vpn prio 500

# Do NAT on the VPN interface
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

- Make it executable:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/pia-namespace`

- Make a symlink:

`sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/pia-namespace /etc/rc5.d/S99pia-namespace`

- Configure the OVPN file to run in the namespace

`route-up ip route add default dev tun0 table pia-vpn`

- Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to show the following:

Uncomment the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

- Finally start the application in the namespace (for example ping):

`sudo ip netns exec pia ping 8.8.8.8`

The end result is ping hanging or `curl ident.me` not returning an ip address.  I don't exactly know what is occurring or how to proceed.

Comment: Is the openvpn process being run inside the isolated namespace or the root namespace? If in root namespace, how do you start it and how do you make sure that it does not automatically re-route all the traffic (like many openvpn configs already do?).

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding another routing table manually and not just setting some routes from inside the isolated namespace?